# Python - Class from Serial

Tags: python, serial-port

how do I create a class that Inheritates from serial using the python serial module?

I need to create a module so another user can import to his code and create an object by just passing the COM.

This is my module, called py232

```
from serial import Serial

class serialPort(Serial):

def __init__(self, COM):
    serial.__init__(self)
    self.COMPort = COM
    self.baudrate = 9600
    self.bytesize = 8
    self.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
    self.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
    self.timeout = 2

    #serialPort = serial.Serial(port=self.COMPort, baudrate= self.baudrate, stopbits= self.stopbits, parity= self.parity, timeout= self.timeout)
    self.createSerial()
    
def createSerial(self):        
    sPort = serial.Serial(port = self.COMPort, baudrate=self.baudrate, bytesize=self.bytesize, timeout= self.timeout, stopbits = self.stopbits, parity=self.parity)    
    return sPort
```

I am trying to use it in another script:

```
import py232
s = py232.serialPort('COM6')

s.sndSerial('test')
```

Comment: What is `serial`, it is not part of the standard library?

Comment: is actually Serial, I am using Serial module to communicate using RS-232.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just create an instance of serial in a function. No need to create a sub-class.

```
from serial import Serial

def create_serial(port):
    s = Serial(
        port,
        baudrate=9600,
        bytesize=8,
        timeout=2,
        # etc
    )
    return s
```

It can then be used in another script.

```
import py232

s = py232.create_serial('COM6')
```